# Changing out internal sharepoint over to SSL. Requiring SSL on IIS is affecting office web apps

Tags: 2013

I'm changing out internal sharepoint over to ssl and I have issued a certificate for our sharepoint server and one for the office web apps server. I added AAM address and everything seems to be working fine.

One of the odd behaviors I get is that the when I click a link, even though the link has the `https` prefix, it will redirect to the `http` address instead. I figured it was a browser caching issue, but it does it for links directed to the OWA server too.

If I enabled the `Require SSL` setting in IIS, I can't access any documents, and some of the sites on our farm stop working. Is there a way to turn https on and turn off any requests to http?

Comment: Do you have any URL Rewrites in IIS?

Comment: No I don't. I had the idea of the weekend to crawl https and see if that resolved my issue though.

Comment: Yea I'm at a loss. Reset index, and crawled entire web app under https. Links in my top navigation will still point to HTTP instead of HTTPS. Why is the reason for this?